# Download File from FTP-Server in Lazarus

Tags: delphi, lazarus

I Need to download files from a FTP-Server with Lazarus. I have already a function for connecting to the Server but no idea how I can download files from it.

I hope someone can give me a Code example on that.

Connecting to FTP-Server:

```
function connect(Host, Username, Password : string) : boolean;
var
FTP: TFTPSend;
begin
FTP := TFTPSend.Create;

FTP.TargetHost := Host;
FTP.TargetPort := Port;
FTP.AutoTLS := true;
FTP.Username := username;
FTP.Password:= Password;
FTP.Login;
```

Comment: Could you post any code/library that you are using to connect to the server?

Comment: I have found this [http://delphi.cjcsoft.net/viewthread.php?tid=46591] but it doesn't download any file only create one at a specified path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download a file thru [TFTPSend.RetrieveFile](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doc/help/ftpsend.TFTPSend.html#RetrieveFile) function

> function RetrieveFile(const FileName: string; Restore: Boolean):
>   Boolean; virtual;

```
var
 FTP: TFTPSend;
begin
  FTP := TFTPSend.Create;
  try
    ....
      FTP.DirectFileName := LocalPath;
      FTP.DirectFile     := True;
      FTP.RetrieveFile(RemotePath, True);
    ....
  finally
    FTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Also you can use this function [FtpGetFile](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doc/help/ftpsend.html#FtpGetFile)

> function FtpGetFile(const IP, Port, FileName, LocalFile, User, Pass:
>   string): Boolean;

---

**Update**
To download all files in given directory you need to perform loop as below:

```
  FTP.DirectFile:=True;
  if FTP.List('', False) then
    for I := 0 to FTP.FtpList.Count-1 do begin
        FTP.DirectFileName := FTP.FtpList[I].FileName;
        FTP.RetrieveFile(FTP.FtpList[I].FileName, True);
    end;
```

Check [TFTPSend.List](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doc/help/ftpsend.TFTPSend.html#List) for more information.

Comment: I like the try finally in the answer, that should be the first thing to learn imo

Comment: I have already tried it with FtpGetFile but my Problem is, that i don't know the Name of the file. And it should download all files from one direcotry on the ftp server

Comment: @GuidoG I already knew the try finally Methode and I also used it in my program I haven't put in my Question because I had some Problems with putting the Code in the Question.

Comment: @user12346352 `but my Problem is, that i don't know the Name of the file` This is different Q, You should mention that in the Q. What you can do is perform loop to to target directory and download all the files.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if the command PASV  (when `FTP.Passive:=true`) is returned to a private address by mistake on the remote server firewall config? eg'227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,148,37,129,44)'. We receiving error 425 can't open data connection!
I am using synapse 4.0 and Lazarus 2.0.10. In most famous ftp clients (filezilla,winscp etc) user can replace or better force the public ip of remote server before send a data command to ftp server. With few code line addition to Class TFTPSend in unit ftpsend we can reestablish lost data connection.
a) Add a boolean variable to protected part of class eg `FForceIP: Boolean;`
b) Add a boolean property to published part of class eg `property ForceIP: Boolean read FForceIP write FForceIP;` permits to change the above variable
c) At `function TFTPSend.DataSocket: boolean;` after the command `FDSock.CloseSocket;` in passive mode first part of function adding the following command `if FForceIP then FDataIP:=FTargetHost;` that replaces private IP given by PASV command with the IP of remote ftp server.
d) To enable force remote host IP address just set `FTP.Passive:= True;` and `FTP.ForceIP:= True;`. Τhe data channel is now returning and operating normally!